# perl script to implement sudo login in linux

Tags: perl, unix

I wrote a script in perl which should actually `sudo`to root in linux using the password. After the login, it has to call a shell script. However once the login is done, all the other commands become background process and hence do not execute.

Comment: We can't really help you fix code we don't see. Please [edit] your question to include the relevant parts of your script.

Comment: If you're going to make the script enter a password to become root, why not just make the script setuid root?

Comment: @FatalError: scripts **cannot** be run setuid root, if you did not know that

Comment: @mvp: Didn't realize but it makes sense. The interpreter would have to be the one with setuid root.

Comment: @FatalError: Actually, it's not that the interpreter needs to be suid root. Scripts are specifically prevented from being suid as a matter of security policy. Allowing suid scripts creates a race condition in which an attacker can replace the suid script in the time between when the interpreter is invoked and when the interpreter reads the script, thus causing the interpreter to run the attacker's code with elevated privileges.

Comment: Scripts with access to a root (or root-equivalent) password make me _extremely_ nervous. I would strongly suggest configuring `sudo` to allow the script to run the specific command(s) in question via passwordless `sudo` and then removing the password from the script.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write `sudo` equivalent on Perl. This is cus Perl is scripting language and is contains `#!/usr/bin/perl` in begining. So, when you run it actually **exec**-s into `/usr/bin/perl sudo.pl`. And, of course, Perl binary does not have suid flag.

Also, your question... it looks "malwary"...

Answer (score 0):

For interactive session, you can make use of perl Expect package.
https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Expect/Expect.pod